# jquery stops working when I add some new code

Tags: jquery

I'm kind of new to jquery so I'm sorry if this question is dumb. The problem that I'm having is that I'm building off of some code that somebody else wrote before hand, but when I try to add the following code involving vars and if statements

```
var $points = $('#points');
if($points>0){
    $points.removeClass('red').addCLass('green');
}
else{
    $points.removeClass('green').addCLass('red');
}

$points.html(points);
});
```

all the code above it stops working. To save some time, every code above it is just a slight variable of the following code:

```
$('#container').hover(function() {
  $('#container').addClass('hover1');
    }, function() {
  $('#container').removeClass('hover1')
});
```

The weird thing is that the person started the code off with:

```
$(function (){
```

instead of

```
$(document).ready(function(){
```

which is what I'm used to. Can somebody tell me what exactly is going on and how I could fix it? Thanks.

Comment: *"The weird thing is that the person started the code off with: [...]"* I recommend to read the jQuery tutorial: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/ . Your code doesn't work because you have syntax errors (last line, `});`). That would be clearer if you indented the code properly. And comparing a jQuery object to a number does make a lot of sense. Have a look at a [JavaScript tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide) and explain what you intended to do with that code. Also, the method is called `addClass` not `addCLass`.

Comment: Alrighty, I guess that tutorial about the $(function(){ was easy enough. And thank you for catching that error, but I tried changing addCLass to addClass and it still wasn't working. I kind of thought it was obvious what I was trying to do with my code haha I guess not. I assigned certain number values on my page (in <p></p> tags) the ID #points (ex: <p id='points'>9808</p>. If its negative, I want the color to be red and green if its positive.

Comment: @user3648348 Your comment suggests that you have have several elements with the id 'points', there should be only one with this id. You would use `text()` to get the value inside a p-tag.

Comment: @AndyG would using $(this) work? Would that change the individual point value colors separately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(function(){
     ...
});
```

is the same as

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     ...
});
```

With that in mind, you do need one or the other to run jQuery code, because otherwise jQuery will run its code before the DOM has loaded, and $('#points'), or any selector for that matter, will return an empty array.

Also, I'm pretty sure you can't say "CLass", it has to be "Class".

Not sure what you mean by $points>0.  Please clarify?

Hope that helps!

Comment: by $points>0 I was trying to say that if points was positive. If it was, I was trying to change the color to green

Comment: How about `$points.html().toInt()>0` or something?  Or if it's a field in a form, you could try `$points.val().toInt()>0`.

Comment: `toInt()` doesn't exist in JavaScript.

Comment: Whoops, sorry, custom defined function.  use parseInt. `parseInt($points.html())>0`

Comment: @Scelesto oh snap, that works! I appreciate it man. Well it works for 1 of the points. The other points stay the same though. I actually figured out what was going on with my original problem. I just had to delete the extra });

Comment: That's cause `#id` only works once.  Use `.class` to do multiples.